# How to create an ansible task to update golang

Tags: go, ansible, yaml, continuous-integration

I want to update golang version to the latest in some dev servers, and I wanted to add a task for this. I was thinking of doing something like this-

```
- name: Upgrade golang
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: 'golang'
    state: latest
```

but Im not sure if this would work, plus I dont think if writing "golang" in the name section is enough.
Could you please suggest what this task should look like if I just want to update golang to the latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state: latest` will update the specified package if it’s not of the latest available version (see [Ansible Docs: `yum` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html)). Your task should work. For `name` you have to write the package name, as you used for installation.

If you want to update other packages that are not themselves a dependency of `golang`, you must specify them separately. Packages that `golang` depends on are automatically resolved and installed by *yum*.

If you want to specify multiple packages, you can pass them as a list to for `name`. For example:

```
- name: Upgrade golang
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name:
      - golang
      - golang-docker-dev
      - golang-collectd-dev
    state: latest
```